# "Not that you are necessarily looking for a change" - does something sound not right?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I was messaging a colleague of mine, who I think might be interested in a job listing that I came across. I wrote:

> Not that you're necessarily looking for a change, but this sounds like something you could be interested in

I want to convey that he might not necessarily be looking for a change, but this could be interesting to him. Somehow the construction of my sentence seems weird, and not completely correct to me. Of course I could easily write it a different way, but can anyone suggest why this sounds wrong (or right?)?

Or in other words, is there any way to convey the same using that sentence structure (Not that...., but...)?

Comment: Depends on your relationship with the person, and how you would normally interact.  One might say "On the off chance that you're interested..." or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes sense to me. If I were writing something like that it would be pretty close...

"Not that you're necessarily looking for a change, but this sounds like something that might interest you."

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In my head it sounds better when I hear something like "Not necessarily are you looking for a change, but if you are, this might be of interest to you".

Comment: Of course, I might just be overthinking it :)

Comment: Language and words can be weird sometimes if you look at it enough. Have you ever noticed how sometimes the spelling of a word just looks bizarre if you stare at it long enough?

Comment: True that! Once I spent a whole day thinking about the word 'is'. Drove me mad :)